# Taking the Cumulative sum of a Column while Selecting only a Specific Sum within that column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I have a table that has a symbol column and a corresponding number for it. Let's say I want the cumulative sum of only specific symbols such as ABC and DEF in this case , How can I build a formula that only takes the cumulative sum of only ABC and DEF and other symbols that I would like to isolate for if necessary rather than the cumulative sum of all the symbols for a given date. An example of a table is below where the answer of the cumulative sum of only ABC and DEF is highlighted in the yellow cell for a specific date. I would also like the formula to be able to choose any specified date.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you know a similar formula using Office 2019?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FILTER` to get a list of qualifying vaues from your table, and `SUM` that.

```
=SUM(FILTER(NameOfTable[stat 1], <Criteria>))
```

The trick is to specify the filter criteria.  You ask for a Date Range, and a list of qualifying Symbols.

Dates are easy

```
(NameOfTable[Date]>=G2)*(NameOfTable[Date]<=G3)
```

Qualifying a list of symbols is a bit harder.  Using a new function `BYROW` it can be done as (available only to insiders at time of writing)

```
(BYROW(--(NameOfTable[Sym]=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(I:I,I:I<>""))),LAMBDA(array,SUM(array))))
```

The whole function:

```
=SUM(FILTER(NameOfTable[stat 1],
  (NameOfTable[Date]>=G2)*
  (NameOfTable[Date]<=G3)*
  (BYROW(--(NameOfTable[Sym]=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(I:I,I:I<>""))), LAMBDA(array, SUM(array))))
))
```

An alternative, not using `BYROWS`

```
MMULT(--(NameOfTable[Sym]=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(I:I,I:I<>""))),1-N(FILTER(I:I,I:I<>"")))
```

So the whole formula is

```
=SUM(FILTER(NameOfTable[stat 1],
  (NameOfTable[Date]>=G2)*
  (NameOfTable[Date]<=G3)*
  MMULT(--(NameOfTable[Sym]=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(I:I,I:I<>""))),1-N(FILTER(I:I,I:I<>"")))
))
```

<sub>Change `NameOftable` to your actual table name</sub>

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you know a similar formula using Office 2019?

Answer (score 0):

You can string together statements with "*" (for "and") and "+" (for "or") with the `FILTER` function to filter on multiple criteria.

If you want a certain date and certain symbols, use something like

```
=SUM(FILTER(sum_range, 
((date_range=date)*
((symbol_range=symbol1)+(symbol_range=symbol2)+...))))
```

For example:

```
=SUM(FILTER($C$2:$C$10,
(($B$2:$B$10=E3)*
(($A$2:$A$10=E4)+($A$2:$A$10=E5)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sum of only specific Single Date, Then use it

```
=SUMPRODUCT((--(A2:A10=E1)+--(A2:A10=F1))*IF(G1="",1,(B2:B10=G1)),C2:C10)
```

If you want the Sum till any Date Then Use it

```
=SUMPRODUCT((--(A2:A10=E1)+--(A2:A10=F1))*IF(G1="",1,(B2:B10<=G1)),C2:C10)
```

If you want Sum between Two given Dates Then

```
=SUMPRODUCT((--(A2:A10=E1)+--(A2:A10=F1))*IF(G1="",1,(B2:B10<=G1))*IF(H1="",1,(B2:B10>=H1)),C2:C10)
```